# creating a testmode through the url parameter which inserts values into a form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, testing, mocking, query-string

As I am fairly new to web application development I am currently having some difficulty in implementing some testing functionality.

As part of the project I am currently working (An MVC 3 Web App for processing payments) I have been asked to create a testmode which can be accessed through the URL in this manner:

```
http://websiteurl?testmode=1
```

The idea behind this is that when one of the development team adds the testmode parameter to the URL a set of form values are auto generated in order to save time on entering data each time the application is tested.

Currently I have an if statement in the controller which uses Request.QueryString to set the parameter below is the code that I am currently using:

```
if (Request.QueryString.AllKey.Contains("tm"))
{
     if (Request.QueryString["tm"] == 1)
     {
         insert values to be generated
     }
}
```

Given the context what if any would be the best method of achieving this?

Would it be possible to using a mocking framework such as Moq or RhinoMocks to create a fake repository rather than retrieving results from a database or would it be better to have test data preloaded in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with I would encapsulate your "TestMode" check.

I would create a base controller and and add the following property:

```
// I would consider retrieving this from web.config
protected string testModeKey = "tm";

public bool IsTestContext
{
   get
   {
      return Request.QueryString[testModeKey] != null;
   }
}
```

Alternatively, consider writing an extension method for the HttpRequest:

```
public static bool IsTestContext(this HttpRequest request, string testModeKey = "tm")
{
   request.QueryString[testModeKey] != null;
}
```

This is out of the way. Let's think how we could insert the values. I'm making few assumptions here, but I'd be interested in making controller unit-testable.

I'm assuming that your data is returned from some `IDataRepository` and you have two implementations of repository: FakeDataRepository and ReadDataRepository.

You could then write a factory or a simple ifelse statement to decide which repository to use.

```
IDataRepository DataRepository { get; set; }

if (Request.IsTestContext)
   DataRepository = new FakeDataRepository();
else
   DataRepository = new RealDataRepository();
```

This would work for what you want it to do, but it's not a good way forward in my opinion. I would look into unit testing your controllers. Can you provide more details on what you would like to test, as I'm making quite a few assumptions and guesses here?

Answer (score 0):

So that you have a few details on how the application is currently laid out I have provided details below:

The basic structure of the application follow the project silk template, breaking down the application into Business Logic, Data Tier, Presentation and Unit Tests, the controller that I am implementing this testmode in already inherits from a base controller which currently contains an implementation of the Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation pattern.

the service locator access four services found in the Business Logic Domain project, three of these access repositories that contain values for three drop down lists the fourth access an implementation of the transaction service for the payment solution (SagePay) that has been integrated into the app this uses the SagePayMvc.dll.

All of the repositories inherit from a Base Repository I currently have six repositories that inherit from this base, three again are for populating drop down lists the other three store information on Students, Card Holders and Order Details the testmode is basically accessing the Student Repository which is currently to populate a student details form currently the Card Holder details can be populated using JQuery.

There are two sets of models one set in the Business Logic and the other in the Data Tier, with the model validation being defined in thee Business Logic Domain.

The View Model through which I access the models is currently using the Domain Model.

In order to create the repositories I am using the Entity Framework Code First approach, it currently creates the repositories as a database where the tables correspond to each of the defined models.

The purpose of the this testmode is to quickly populate the non-unique form fields (I currently have some logic implemented that stop Students from entering a name that already exists) so that when other members of the team are using the application they can quickly assess if the application is working it is particularly for the design team as they apply styling to application.

I currently have one Test Class setup which is testing the assertion that the Student Repository can create a new student the data I have defined in here access a fake repository defined using Moq.

Comment: should also note this will be one of four test modes other, one will populate the form with values for paying in the US, one saves values to a different database and the fourth which I have already completed redirects to the success page